# Modeling account for rest communication cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I need to model account (first name, last name, email as username etc.) in cassandra along with currently active token.

My initial idea was to create `account_by_email` which will have skinny row partitioned by email with static columns and have clustering by `access_token` (and maybe TTL) and than you can always find access token based on current email.

But we have requirement that clients will send after login only `access_token` and based on it current user must be pulled from DB.

I can create one more table where email will be partitioned by `access_token` but that seams to me as overhead and lot of partitions. Then I could get email from `access_token` and get user by email always.

Any better ideas and approaches, it seams that this is common use case but I cannot find any modeling details when cassandra is used as storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can create one more table where email will be partitioned by access_token but that seams to me as overhead and lot of partitions.

What's wrong with a large number of partitions it a table? It's definitely a correct Cassandra-way of doing things:

```
create table users (
  email text primary key,
  first_name text,
  last_name text,
  current_token text
);

create table tokens (
  auth_token text primary key,
  valid_until timestamp,
  email text
);
```

So you have a separate tables for users, and the `tokens` table which has token as a partition key. With this model you can:

- set a new token for a user by updating users.current_token with TTL and inserting a new token row to `tokens` table.
- get user email by token, even if the token was expired.
- get current user's active token.
- have full token history for a user (but no way to run effective queries for that type of information, you can use Spark/SparkSQL/Hive for that).
- automatically expire tokens by setting TTL for a single `current_token` column.

Comment: Instead of adding `current_token` to users table might be a good idea to make email, first and last name as static and have clustering on UDT token which will be ordered DESC. That way history can be solved and when new token is generated only insert is needed in both tables. Thanks for answer, it was my chain of thoughts as well but wanted to get some more ideas.

Comment: @NenadBozic in that case, you can separate token logic away from user table. Have two separate tables for access token puproses, one with by email as partition key and the other with access token as partition key. I some how feel reusing table such as user to keep history is not a good idea.